# Where can I find MITEoR 150 Mhz radio data?

Tags: radio-astronomy, software, sky-survey

I was working on the Aladin Sky Atlas v12 software and while working on the radio data, I came across this Radio sky survey that said MITEoR 150 MHz. Initially, I mistook it to be GMRT because GMRT also operates on the same frequency range. Later I noticed that this survey is different; moreover, its data isn't available on Aladin as well.
Hence, I wish to know if there is any source from where I can get the data of this sky survey and also if there's some way to upload the same onto Aladin software.

Comment: Did you contact any of the authors who worked with those data or the instrumentation and what did they reply?

Comment: Umm..no, I didn't. I thought, I was missing out some component to get the data and so thought of enquiring here. I'll enquire with them and get back.

Comment: @DhruvNayak you can also say "No I didn't." and leave it at that. There is no obligation to make personal contact with scientists before you can ask a question here in Stack Exchange. It's certainly a good idea but absolutely not required.